# Compile for x64 with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, 64-bit

Question: 
Assume a C++ hello world program, non .NET.
With Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010, how can I compile a 64-Bit application ?
I have a 64 Bit Windows, but by default, VS seems to compile 32 bit executables...

On Linux with g++, I can use -m32 and -m64, but how can I compile a 64 bit solution with Windows ? Is it even possible with 2005 ? Or does one need 2008 or even 2010 Beta, or even some x64 SDK ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a step-by-step instructions by Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it may just be that you haven't [set the correct target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx). It is possible to also build x64 applications on an x86 using the cross compiler tools.